# How to include a call to ncat to a bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to flush a memcached instance from a bash script, I found the following command which do the job:

```
echo 'flush_all' | ncat localhost 11211
```

But my problem is that the script doesn't continue next command, it stops with `ncat`'s response:

[image]

If I manually send the command on my console I need to do a `CTRL+C` to kill the process.

I think it's a normal behaviour of `echo` or `ncat` command, but I don't know to bypass it... Do you know how to workaround it?

NB: my OS is a Redhat6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, just add the send-only option:

```
echo 'flush_all' | ncat localhost 11211 --send-only
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script to go on, you can launch this in the background. (with the `&`)

```
before-cmd ...

echo 'flush_all' | ncat localhost 11211  &   

after-cmd....
```

Comment: So it starts a process which will never end?

Comment: you can add a `pkill` with matching ncat localhost command to do it automaticaly for you at the end of the script